# how to do unit testing with phpstorm and zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit, pear, phpstorm

i am trying to run some testing on my framework with phpstorm.

i am working with xampp and i have php unit installed.

the framework is located:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\zend\application\
C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\zend\library\
C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\zend\library\zend\...
...
```

the php interpreter i set up is php 5.4.4

when i run the testing i get

C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php --no-configuration C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\zend
Testing started at 2:24 PM ...

Warning: require_once(Zend/Cache/Backend/ExtendedInterface.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\zend\library\Zend\Cache\Backend\Test.php on line 27

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Cache/Backend/ExtendedInterface.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\zend\library\Zend\Cache\Backend\Test.php on line 27

Process finished with exit code 255

in Test.php in the zend library there is an include `require_once 'Zend/Cache/Backend/ExtendedInterface.php';` and it seems that the ide can't figure out the path.

any ideas on this issue?

thanks

Comment: You need to add those paths (at very least the one for PHPUnit) to `include_path=` variable in your php.ini (execute `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to see where php.ini is loaded from). All other paths -- you can dynamically alter `include_path` from your bootstrap.php file that will be loaded by PHPUnit ... or use your autoloaders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure additional include paths. I suggest you do that with your project settings. To do that, double click *[image: External Libraries] External Libraries*  at the end of the [*Project Tool Window*](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/project-tool-window.html).

When you call the unit tests, PHPStorm will automatically add those.

Just add the Zend Framework path as an include path and you should have solved these problems.

Comment: i added some more paths but for some reason i only see the php one, i believe fron c:/xampp/php